# Couldn't load file or assembly in WP8.1 Application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a simple WP 8.1 app for myself.
I need a `DockPanel` on one of the pages, so I added a reference to *System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll* (Silverlight 4) to my project and created a namespace

```
<xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit">
```

in XAML. I can see a `DockPanel` class in the list of classes of the namespace, but when I add it to the page I get exception

> The element DockPanel can not be displayed because of a problem with System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31b3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.*". Do anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, We can't use the assemblies which target is Windows Phone 8.0(Silverlight). For example, namespace `System.Windows.Controls` has been replaced by `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`. But you can use Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 to do this. Or coding `DockPanel` yourself with sourcecode in toolkit.